# Solve for b: $a^2 = b^2 c^2 - b^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $c>b$ which leads to $b^2 c^2 - b^4 > 0$ is it possible to solve for b in the equation

$$a^2=b^2 c^2 - b^4$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $b^2=w$ so you have the equation $w^2-c^2w+a^2=0$. Now solve to $w$.

Comment: From there you use the quadratic formula. Right?

Comment: Don't forget to find $b$ from $w$, since $w=b^2$.